# LibGDX multi-touch implementation, game development

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multi-touch

I am currently developing an android game using LibGdx. I am trying to get the multi touch functionality working as the game requires the player to have one thumb to control the character and the other to click buttons.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
                final int iX = Gdx.input.getX(i);
                if (iX > screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                    buttontouch = true;
                } else {
                    buttontouch = false;
                }

                if (iX <= screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                    playertouch = true;
                }else{
                    playertouch = false;
                }

            }
        }


if (playertouch){
etc...
}
if(buttontouch){
etc...
}
```

The player can be moved and the buttons pressed, but not at the same time :( ... which is what i need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Logic which moves your character should be called inside `for` circle. You should move your character every circle iteration (if button was clicked) Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
            final int iX = Gdx.input.getX(i);
            if (iX > screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                buttontouch = true;
            } else {
                buttontouch = false;
            }

            if (iX <= screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                playertouch = true;
            }else{
                playertouch = false;
            }
        }
//Logic here!
if (playertouch){
etc...
}
if(buttontouch){
etc...
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I made the change, but still each function only works separately. Any ideas :S

Answer (score 1):

Ok I seemed to have worked out an answer.
added

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
```

below in each boolean if

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)){
            final int iX = Gdx.input.getX(i);
            if (iX > screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                buttontouch = true;
            } else {
                buttontouch = false;
            }

            if (iX <= screenwidth - screenwidth / 14) {
                playertouch = true;
            }else{
                playertouch = false;
            }
        }
  }
//Logic here!
if (playertouch){
if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
etc...
}
}
if(buttontouch){
if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i)) {
etc...
}
}
    }
```